# Export only visible columns in datagridview to Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I'm currently developing a software as required in my OJT. Im trying to export my datagrid to an excel file. the problem is even if i put checkbox to set the visibility of specific column to false and it hides on my datagrid but when the excel file is generated, the columns are still visible. heres my code, and thank you.

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        TabPage1.Enabled = False
        TabPage2.Enabled = False
        'Form3.Show()'


        DATAGRIDVIEW_TO_EXCEL((DataGridView1)) 
    End Sub
    '-------------------------------------------------Excel------------------------------------------------'
    Private Sub DATAGRIDVIEW_TO_EXCEL(ByVal DGV As DataGridView)
        Try
            Dim DTB = New DataTable, RWS As Integer, CLS As Integer
                For CLS = 0 To DGV.ColumnCount - 1 
                    DTB.Columns.Add(DGV.Columns(CLS).Name.ToString)
                Next

                Dim DRW As DataRow

                For RWS = 0 To DGV.Rows.Count - 1 
                    DRW = DTB.NewRow

                    For CLS = 0 To DGV.ColumnCount - 1
                        Try
                            DRW(DTB.Columns(CLS).ColumnName.ToString) = DGV.Rows(RWS).Cells(CLS).Value.ToString
                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try
                    Next

                    DTB.Rows.Add(DRW)
                Next

                DTB.AcceptChanges()

                Dim DST As New DataSet
                DST.Tables.Add(DTB)
                Dim FLE As String = "E:\Export\Export.xml" 
                DTB.WriteXml(FLE)
                Dim EXL As String = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.exe" 
                Shell(Chr(34) & EXL & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & FLE & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus) 

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        '------------------------------------------------------Excel--------------------------------------------------------'



    End Sub
```

Here is how i hide my columns

```
   Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            Me.GSIS.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.GSIS.Visible = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            Me.PAGIBIG.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.PAGIBIG.Visible = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
            Me.PHILHEALTH.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.PHILHEALTH.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub CheckBox4_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox4.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
            Me.SSS.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.SSS.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox5.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
            Me.TIN.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.TIN.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox6_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox5.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then
            Me.AgencyEmployeeNo.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.AgencyEmployeeNo.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Before adding a Column to the Excel just check it's visible: `If ColumnVisible.checked = True Then 'Write to excel End If`

Comment: No problem! My Code isn't exact but it's so you can understand the principal you still need to adapt it to your desired column.

Comment: hmmm.. im actually having a little difficulty in this concept. can you elaborate more? if not it's okay. thank you so much for quick response.

Comment: Well first we would need to see how you hide your columns

Comment: Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            Me.GSIS.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.GSIS.Visible = True
        End If

    End Sub

 and so on and so on.. its actually a series of checkboxes for filtering the datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change this:

```
For CLS = 0 To DGV.ColumnCount - 1 
    DTB.Columns.Add(DGV.Columns(CLS).Name.ToString)
Next
```

To something like this:

```
'For Every Column in the DataGridView
For Each Col as DataGridViewColumn in DGV.Columns
   If Checkbox1.checked = True AND Col.Name = GSIS.Name Then
       DTB.Columns.Add(Col.Name.ToString)
   End If
   'If checkbox2 etc etc 
Next
```

The Ideal so you wouldn't have to copy paste so much would be to create a class where you would associate a **visibility** property for each col and would just check that property in a loop.

/!\ Be Careful /!\

I added **Col.Nale = GSIS.Name** assuming **GSIS** was a **Column** but in your code it may not be the case. So try to **understand** the code instead of copy pasting.

Comment: Thanks man. However, the only thing filtered are the Headernames in Excel and not the contents. All the data are still attached and are not filtered like the headernames.
[Here is the Datagridview with selected Columns that will be exported]
(http://imgur.com/E4fQ6GG)
[And here is the output of the excel file which the contents are not filtered only the headernames]
(http://imgur.com/Wed0Xha)

Comment: I think the problem is even when you are hiding the column you are exporting all to the excel you need make sure to skip the column which are hidden. or just copy the final dataset with all hidden column to new temporary dataset and export that one.

Comment: Ahhh yes! ok now i get it! thanks man. This is actually my ojt for the whole 300hours, cause im new to programming. lol so i have lots of time to study. XD

Comment: No problem! @PhilipJohnREndrinal if the problem is solved don't forget mark the answer.